# Com DLL Written in C# - Function being called multiple times

Tags: c#, com, vb6

I have a DLL written in C# (4.0) for COM, created in VS2010.  Upgrading is not an option at this time. Operating systems which have had the problem include but may not be limited to: Win XP, Win Vista, Win 7 and I think Win 8.  (I have not had a chance to verify the last)

The DLL is being called by a VB 6.0 application.  I have event log entries which allow me to see the activity of the functions being called with steps along the way of the function being logged for my review. The DLL registers fine and functions properly in QA.  It registers and appears to have been functioning fine in production until a recent problem was discovered.

My problem is that the logs show sometimes a function is being called multiple times over 1 to 2.5 minutes.  The logs show that the function is being called every .02 milliseconds. I know that the function is being called or restarted from the beginning rather looping within the function because of the steps I log.  The function is a simple function with no parameters that calls a web service and returns a bool.

I have looked to make sure there is no looping code in either the calling application or the DLL that could explain the problem.

I can not reproduce the problem in my environment.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can proceed to debug this in the field?  I am sure there has to be some monitoring tools but I am unaware of what it could be. It "feels" like a communication error between the calling application and the DLL but I am not sure how to debug that.

Comment: Which function is being called? Did you exclude internal calls (when dll method call own methods)? It could be the logger itself (you didn't show/tell how exactly you log that, yet you trust it).

Comment: There are no internal calls.  The logged entries have been verified against the web service so I know they are correct. In other words the DLL calls a web service.  This web service also has a log.  Each time the function appears to restart there is a transaction id.  This transaction id is unique. The log entries match. 

The log on the calling computer is the event log while the log on the web service server is logged to a SQL Server Database.

The function being called is a custom function with no input parameters and returns a bool.

Comment: To be clear a new transaction id is created as the first line of the function. Each 2 milliseconds a new transaction id is created which indicates to me that the function is being called again.  I am sure that the problem lies in the communication layer between the VB 6 app and the DLL.  It almost acts like the VB 6.0 application does not get a response, detaches, reattaches and tries again repeatedly. I just don't know how to monitor or debug that.

Comment: It is a DLL Hell symptom.  A rock-hard requirement for COM libraries is that if you change an interface then you *must* change the [Guid] of the interface.  If you don't then unpleasant things will happen when the client program expects the old interface but has to work with the new interface.  It can call the completely wrong method.  If that is a simple method with no arguments then the odds greatly increase that the program doesn't crash and burn from running the completely wrong code.

Comment: First time registration so I am fairly sure not the problem.  Any suggestion as to HOW to debug the communication between VB 6 and DLL?  Maybe something like a timeout setting?

Comment: Run the VB6 app in the VB6 debugger. In C++ one would run WinDbg and put breakpoints on the C++ COM calls. I'm not a NET programmer but surely C# has a debugger. My guess is that something has hit an error and your error handling is wrong.